# Friending between test users via API does not seem to work

Tags: testing, facebook-graph-api

I've created a set of test users and am now trying to programatically friend them to each other using the PHP Facebook API. Below is a sample code to do so between F1 and F2.

```
$b = $fb->api("/" . $f1['id'] . "/friends/" . $f2['id'] . "/?method=post&access_token=" . urlencode($a[1]));
$b = $fb->api("/" . $f2['id'] . "/friends/" . $f1['id'] . "/?method=post&access_token=" . urlencode($a[1]));
```

I've checked the value of the ids and the application access token is correct. $b is set to an array with an empty 'data' element. I had expected a true/false based on the documentation.

When I log on as F1 or F2, neither shows any friends. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you make it work with `curl` (or similar) first, then check to see that the PHP code makes the same request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion Darthenius. I did so and did not have further luck. So I tried some more stuff. The code below finally worked. It appears one much use the access_tokens for the individual users:

```
$fb->setAccessToken($f1['access_token']);
$b = $fb->api('/'.$f1['id'].'/friends/'.$f2['id'], "POST");
$fb->setAccessToken($f2['access_token']);
$b = $fb->api('/'.$f2['id'].'/friends/'.$f1['id'], "POST");
```

This was contrary to Facebook's documentation which says an app access token will work. At present, Note you need to handle a 522 exception when users are already friends.

You can get a user's current friends and not refriend them:

```
//Could avoid checking members of this list:
$fb->setAccessToken($f1['access_token']);
$current_friends = $fb->api('/'.$f1['id'].'/friends', "GET");
```